# Get certain xml node and save the value

Tags: c#, xml

Considering the following XML:

```
<Stations>
 <Station>
  <Code>HT</Code>
  <Type>123</Type>
  <Names>
    <Short>H'bosch</Short>
    <Middle>Den Bosch</Middle>
    <Long>'s-Hertogenbosch</Long>
  </Names>
  <Country>NL</Country>
</Station>
</Stations>
```

There are multiple  nodes. I need the value of each  node.
I've got the XML from a webpage (http://webservices.ns.nl/ns-api-stations-v2)

Login (--) Pass (--)

Currently i take the XML as a string and parse it to a XDocument.

```
var xml = XDocument.Parse(xmlString);
foreach (var e in xml.Elements("Long"))
{
   var stationName = e.ToString();
}
```

Comment: which field are you trying to get?

Comment: I tried to get the stationname Long as you can see in the 2nd code example. @Nathan-Weeler got me the right solution in the answers below. Note that i use an XmlString (not an XmlStream).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can retrieve "Station" nodes using XPath, then get each subsequent child node using more XPath. This example isn't using Linq, which it looks like you possibly are trying to do from your question, but here it is:

```
XmlDocument xml = new XmlDocument();
xml.Load(xmlStream);
XmlNodeList stations = xml.SelectNodes("//Station");

foreach (XmlNode station in stations)
{
    var code = station.SelectSingleNode("Code").InnerXml;
    var type = station.SelectSingleNode("Type").InnerXml;
    var longName = station.SelectSingleNode("Names/Long").InnerXml;
    var blah = "you should get the point by now";
}
```

**NOTE: If your `xmlStream` variable is a `String`, rather than a `Stream`, use `xml.LoadXml(xmlStream);` for line 2, instead of `xml.Load(xmlStream)`. If this is the case, I would also encourage you to name your variable to be more accurately descriptive of the object you're working with (aka. `xmlString`).**

Comment: Hmm i seem to be getting an error: 
A first chance exception of type 'System.UriFormatException' occurred in System.dll

Comment: @User1766381 - I assumed your xmlStream was a Stream object. If it's just a string of XML, use `xml.LoadXml(xmlStream)` instead. Also, if it's not a Stream, consider changing your variable name in your source code to be accurately descriptive.

Comment: No problem! Good luck with the rest of your project!

Answer (score 0):

This will give you all the values of "Long" for every Station element.

```
var xml = XDocument.Parse(xmlStream);
var longStationNames = xml.Elements("Long").Select(e => e.Value);
```